# Error in openssl_decrypt(encrypted_data, key = decryption_key) : could not find function "openssl_decrypt"

Tags: r, openssl

I want to apply one ssl wrapper function on top of my existing function so that without changing to my existing function i can apply ssl wrapper on top of that. my_function is my existing function that i can not change or touch that is fixed.
so i am just applying decorator concept of python here.

Error in openssl_decrypt(encrypted_data, key = decryption_key) :
could not find function "openssl_decrypt"

Code :

```
library(openssl)

# Define a function to encrypt data
encrypt_data <- function(data, encryption_key) {
  encrypted_data <- openssl_encrypt(data, key = encryption_key)
  return(encrypted_data)
}

# Define a function to decrypt data
decrypt_data <- function(encrypted_data, decryption_key) {
  decrypted_data <- openssl_decrypt(encrypted_data, key = decryption_key)
  return(decrypted_data)
}

# Define a decorator function with encryption and decryption
my_secure_decorator <- function(func, encryption_key, decryption_key) {
  inner_function <- function(...) {
    # Encrypt the input data
    encrypted_args <- lapply(list(...), function(arg) {
      if (is.character(arg)) {
        return(encrypt_data(arg, encryption_key))
      } else {
        return(arg)
      }
    })
    
    cat("Before function call\n")
    result <- do.call(func, encrypted_args)
    cat("After function call\n")
    
    # Decrypt the result
    decrypted_result <- decrypt_data(result, decryption_key)
    
    return(decrypted_result)
  }
  return(inner_function)
}

# Create a function and decorate it with encryption and decryption
my_function <- function(a, b) {
  cat("Inside my_function\n")
  cat("Consider this as an external fuction or package or library \n")
  return(a + b)
}

# Encryption and decryption keys (replace with your own keys)
encryption_key <- "YourEncryptionKey123"
decryption_key <- "YourDecryptionKey456"

decorated_function <- my_secure_decorator(my_function, encryption_key, decryption_key)

# Call the decorated function
result <- decorated_function(2, 3)
cat("Decrypted Result:", result, "\n")
```